# Configuring Local Notifications in expo for android devices?

Tags: android, react-native, notifications, expo, uilocalnotification

I am fairly new to react-native and still learning. I am trying to configure local notifications for an android device, but it's not working. While trying to solve this issue, I learned that Permissions has moved out of expo, and Notifications for android require a separate object to be created for sound and vibration to work. The examples on the other websites also do not seem to work. (maybe there is an update). I have already tried importing "Permissions" from the new "expo-permissions" but still, it is not working! Please help!!

Here is my code:

```
import Notifications from 'expo';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
```

```
async obtainNotificationPermission() {
        let permission = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.USER_FACING_NOTIFICATIONS)

        if (permission.status !== 'granted') {
            permission =await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.USER_FACING_NOTIFICATION);
            console.log("Permission Status: "+permission);
            if (permission.status !== 'granted') {
                Alert.alert('Permission not granted to show notifications!')
            }
        }
        return permission;
    }

    async presentLocalNotification(date) {
        await this.obtainNotificationPermission();
        console.log("Permission Status: "+this.obtainNotificationPermission());
        Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync({
            title: 'Your Reservation',
            body: 'Reservation for '+ date + ' requested',
            ios: {
                sound: true
            },
            android: {
                sound: true,
                vibrate: true,
                color: '#512DA8'
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this line

```
import Notifications from 'expo';
```

insert

```
import { Notifications } from 'expo';
```